# IE-only html ignored by IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am trying to learn how to use IE-only conditionals in html, but my IE simply ignores them.  Here is a complete, minimal example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
  <p>Test: <!--[if IE]>You're using IE.<![endif]--></p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I view this using IE 10.0.9200.16576 on Windows 7, the "You're using IE" message does not appear.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why exactly are you using IE-only conditionals in 2013 ? In IE10 ?What problem are you trying to circumvent ?

Comment: It's a long story, but I have unfortunately discovered a CSS3 standards-violating behavior of IE10 (and presumably all earlier versions) that I must work around somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer, as of version 10, no longer supports conditional comments.

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer
>   10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and
>   compliance with HTML5. This means that Conditional Comments are now
>   treated as regular comments, just like in other browsers. This change
>   can impact pages written exclusively for Windows Internet Explorer or
>   pages that use browser sniffing to alter their behavior in Internet
>   Explorer.

— http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: +1 Silly Microsoft adding their own codes then removing them in a later version!

Answer (score 1):

IE10 doesn't support conditional comments anymore: http://www.therailsview.com/2012/02/internet-explorer-10-to-no-longer-support-conditional-comments/